# Xdebug when you don't have all files locally available

Tags: wordpress, docker, xdebug

I have a full LAMP stack running in Docker. Only a subfolder of the `htdocs` is what I have locally for editing, the rest of the web application is provisioned when my container is run, with my local files for editing sync'd where they need to go.

Xdebug is installed and I'm able to connect to it fine from my host using `pugdebug` or `PhpStorm`. In `PhpStorm`, when I start a debugging session, it first hits a path I cannot map, so I cannot proceed from there.

Is the only solution to mirror the full web application locally?

The local files for editing are a [WordPress plugin](http://github.com/leonstafford/wordpress-static-html-plugin) and the web application is WordPress.

Comment: All files that will be participating in the debug process need to be available to PhpStorm. If Xdebug initiates debug session with a file that is not available to IDE .. then PhpStorm will be unable to handle the rest of request (as you may have even more hits to the code that is outside of your locally available files). For IDE it's a signal (a good sign) that something is wrong with the setup already... so why continue and take a risk to make possible mess/confusion later. But there are some settings available in PhpStorm -- maybe they can help with that...

Comment: Thanks. I use Vim primarily, but thought pugdebug or PhpStorm would be easier to test the Xdebug connection than vim-debug. After many hours, I realized that I was just wanting the profiling features of Xdebug, which didn't depend on the xdbg stuff working properly, so I'll go back to `error_log`'ing out to stderr, which `docker log` tails out for me to a tmux window, which I'm more comfortable with.